# Rendering JSON data in Rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm confused by a difference between my localhost and the same app when I've uploaded it to Heroku.

I render JSON on the fly via a controller method and grab that in Javascript using an AJAX request.

On localhost, it's working perfectly. However, when I upload to Heroku, it does not work at all. Not sure why this may be the case. Does it have to do with a difference between how Heroku accesses my model and how my localhost does?

Here are two debug outputs from the same timestamp:

Working:

> Before it was 106.944877, now it is 0 with increments of
>   -84.07055608611111

Not working:

> Before it was 0, now it is 0 with increments of 0

Here's the code:

Controller method #1:

```
# present data to grab for view work
# get/user_data
def user_inst_data
timestamp = params[:time_now]
user_id = params[:user_id]

before = fetch_data_at_time(user_id, timestamp)
after = fetch_data_at_time(user_id, (timestamp.to_i+3600))

response = Hash.new

response['before'] = before
response['after'] = after

render json: response.to_json
end
```

Controller method #2:

```
def fetch_data_at_time(user_id, time_at)
  # convert time to object
  timestamp = Time.at(time_at.to_i)
  # break down timestamp right now
  year = timestamp.year
  month = timestamp.month
  day = timestamp.day
  hour = timestamp.hour+1 #we're 1-indexed

  # find data
  response = UserData.where(:user_id=>user_id, :year=>year, :month=>month, :day=>day, :hour=>hour).select('power')

  return response
end
```

The javascript:

```
function real_time_update(){
  //this function will fake "real-time" updates by grabbing simulated data from the DB
  //continue to update component every 5 seconds
  setTimeout(real_time_update,5000);
  var time = Math.round(((new Date()).getTime())/1000);

  var targetURL = "get/user_data?time_now="+time+"&user_id="+<%= @user.id %>;

  var power_before = 0;
  var power_after = 0;

  // GET data with AJAX request, set function for successful return
  $.get(targetURL, function(data){
    power_before = data.before[0].power;
    power_after = data.after[0].power;

    // after getting data before and after, find increment between them, delta-naught
    var delta = power_after - power_before;

    // scale before power by a percentage based on how much time has elapsed since last hour
    var current_time = new Date();
    var minutes_passed = (current_time.getMinutes())*60;
    var seconds_passed = minutes_passed + (current_time.getSeconds());
    var percent_hour = seconds_passed/3600;

    // calculate increment
    var delta_change = delta*percent_hour;

    // DEBUG----
    console.log("Before it was "+power_before+", now it is "+power_after+" with increments of "+delta_change)

    //add to power_before and update html component
    var power_update = power_before + delta_change;

    // redraw component
    drawChart(power_update);
  })
}
```

Comment: I notice it's been a few hours with no answer.  When I tried to find one, I found the question is pretty confusing.  It's good to have the code, but I think you'll get more help if you simplify.  My only hint is that when values come back as 0, it tends to be a result of `to_int` having an empty or non-numeric input, so that's where I would look.

Comment: Are you sure you have data on Heroku?